# How to partially log in a user after registration in Laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, routes

After filling out the form, I want the user to be redirect first to a page in which the content is the successful registration. The problem now is it is auto-redirected to user `mypage`.

**USER Model**

```
public function register($data){
try {
    $this->name = $data['name'];
    $this->email = $data['email'];
    $this->password = $data['password'];
    $this->save();
    return $this;
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    \Log::error(get_class().':register(): '.$e->getMessage());
    return false;
}
}
```

**Auth\RegisterController**

```
public function registComplete(User $user){
    $data = Session::get('user');
    $data['password'] = Hash::make($data['password']);
    $rtn = $user->register($data);

    Auth::guard('user')->login($rtn);

    return redirect('/regist/complete');
}
```

in my `/regist/complete` route, it is pointed to the function that will display the thanks page. And from there, the user can click the button to be redirected to the users `mypage`, this will be the only time that they can be redirected.

**VIEW**

```
<div class="regist_cont">
        <div class="rgstdn_message">
            <p class="redbig_message">Thanks for registering.</p>
            <p>You can now visit your profile</p>

        </div>
        <a class="btn btn_red" href="{{ url('/mypage') }}">MY PAGE</a>
    </div>
```

If I remove `Auth::guard('user')->login($rtn);`, the user is not auto logged in. But I can't make them logged in when clicking the mypage button. How can I achieved this?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the below line on your controller

```
protected $redirectTo = '/regist/complete';
```

this will overwrite the default redirect to your page

Comment: Then how can I login the user if they click the gotomypage button?

Comment: The controller is not the right place to check if a user is authenticated or not. You should use a middleware for that. To get info on what a middleware is check here http://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware

Comment: you can just have this method on your middleware class:

```public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    //check here if the user is authenticated
    if ( ! $this->auth->user() )
    {
        // here you should redirect to login 
    }

    return $next($request);
}```

Comment: you need to make modification on your `Route` as well

Answer (score 0):

After exploring, I'm able to do it using `Session`.

**Auth\RegisterController**

```
public function registComplete(User $user){
    $data = Session::get('user');
    $data['password'] = Hash::make($data['password']);
    $rtn = $user->register($data);

    Session::put('log', $rtn);
    Session::save();

    return redirect('/regist/complete');
}

public function registSuccess(){
    Auth::guard('user')->login(Session::get('log'));

    return view('user.register.registComplete');
}
```

Since I am also using social media logins, I do this in my `UserController` when redirecting to the mypage.

```
public function index()
{
    if(Session::exists('log')){
        Session::forget('log');
    }

    return view('user.dashboard')->with([
        'user' => Auth::user(),
    ]);
}
```

With this for now, I'm able to achieve what I want to happen. If you have other better approach, I'm also open to it.